# Code Study-New to programming

Tags: python, class, libraries

i am new to programming and have been studying some code to get to know about OOP.Here is what i have understood and need help on,
1) import gym and env=gym.make('String') : This means gym is a library, and make is a class under it? Have we created an object instance?

I understood classes contains methods inside them..i.e functions..but in this case i am not able to decipher clearly.The line after this env.monitor.start()..this contains 3 parts..what does each indiciate..i thought env was an object instantiated earlier.

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.monitor.start('/tmp/cartpole-experiment-1',force=True)
for i_episode in range(20):
    observation = env.reset()
    for t in range(1009):
        env.render()
        print(observation)
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        if done:
            print("Episode finished after {} timesteps".format(t+1))
            break

env.monitor.close()
```

Thanks for your help, apologise if the question is stupid

Comment: It looks like you are confused about the for loop?  You can look that up.  It is a standard programming construct for looping

Comment: Hello, for the loop is not my problems..the accessing such as env.monitor.start..i.e ones related to classes and objects are my problem

Comment: @Thiagarajan, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`gym` can be a package or a module. The `import` statement doesn't tell you what `gym` is.

gym.make means that you are calling a method called 'make' from gym.

`env` is then whatever `make('CartPole-v0')` returns, which may or may not be an object. It has a monitor attribute which seems to be startable, from the method `monitor.start()`, so I'd guess that it is, but you can't know this without looking at the code for gym or calling `type(env)`.

`env.monitor.start()` means that the start method from `env.monitor` is called. What `env.monitor` *is* can't be determined without looking at the code for gym.

Comment: gym.make(XX) can also be the creation of an item of class 'make' defined in gym, that requires a String in its initialization

Comment: then what would env.monitor.start mean..if env were an object perhaps env.monitor would be accesing a method called monitor..but what about the start

Comment: yes, if the method make in gym returns a 'make' object. broadly speaking, It is correct to say that `env` is whatever `gym.make(xx)` returns.

Comment: @Thiagarajan There exist 'class methods', that are functions of a given class, that can be called with the name fo the class (and do not depends of an item the class). If `monitor` is a class in module/package `gym`, then `start can be one such functions`

Comment: @Thiagarajan `env.monitor.start()` calls the `start()` method from whatever `env.monitor` is.

Comment: for example, 
`x = -15` makes `x` an object of type integer.
`x.abs()` calls the integer `abs()` method. It returns `15`. 
`x.abs().hex()` calls the `.hex()` method on `x.abs()`. So `x.abs().hex()` here would evaluate to `F`

Comment: so .hex() method would also be present inside the integer class right

Comment: yes. I'm calling `.hex()` on whatever `x.abs()` is. `x.abs()` is an integer if the `abs()` method on x returns an integer. 

If x is a string `x = 'foo'` , Then `x.abs()` is not  an integer (since strings do not have a `.abs()` method. Then we also can't use `x.abs().hex()`, because `x.abs()` doesn't have a `.hex()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic structure of the above program:

`import` statements bring modules into the program. These modules contain functions. The module is able to use these functions. For example,

```
import myMod as mM

mM.fooFunc()
```

imports a module `myMod` and gives it an alias of `mM`. `fooFunc` belongs inside the module and so we're able to call it.

We don't need aliases. We can also just say

```
import myMod
myMod.fooFunc()
```

but it's slightly less convenient.

`env` is just a name for the return value of the function `gym.make('CartPole-v0')`. Functions always return something, such as an actual object, an integral type (like an integer, or a string), or `None`.

The return value doesn't need to always be stored, such as in `env.monitor.start('/tmp/cartpole-experiment-1',force=True)`. It simply performs some data manipulation.

As for the rest of the program, it's ran by `for-loop`s and `if` statements. [Read about it here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Comment: Okay, i got most of it except env.monitor.start()..say the env=gym.make() has made as a an object..an object can have various attributes...like env.name and so on..but what does it mean when we use the dot operator twice..like env.monitor.start()

Comment: @Thiagarajan Notice that `env.monitor` has no parentheses around monitor. That means that it's an attribute of `env`. The `start` function is then called on the `env.monitor` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`gym`can be a package or module. There is no way to tell what it is by its import statement.

`env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')` can either assign the return value of the call of function `make` from `gym` to variable `env`, or create an item of class `make` and assign that item to variable `env`

`env.monitor.start('/tmp/cartpole-experiment-1',force=True)` means the `env` variable most likely returned an item of class that has a property/subclass called `monitor`. This property/subclass possess a function called `start`

`env` most likely also has a subclass/property `action_space` with a function `sample`

Answer (score 0):

gym.make('CartPole-v0') returns an object.

Therefore, **'env'** is an **object**.

'env' contains a property, **'monitor'**, which is also an **object**.

The **'start'** method is a method of the **'monitor' object**, not the *env object.*

```
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
    env.monitor.start('/tmp/cartpole-experiment-1',force=True)
```

Another way to write it would be (env.monitor).start('/tmp/cartpole-experiment-1',force=True)

For the sake of repetition,

```
 env.reset() 
#env is object, reset is method of env object

 env.render() 
#env is object, render is method of env object

 env.action_space.sample() 
#env is object, action_space is object, sample is method of action_space object

 env.step(action) 
#env is object, step is method of env object
```